# fread is not starting at the beginning of the file

Tags: c, file-io, stream, fread

I am working on a project that involves reading binary data from a file into certain data structures. While testing, I saw that incorrect data was being loaded into these structures. Adding a little debug code (using `ftell`) revealed that `fread` was not starting at the beginning of the file, but at some offset hundreds of bytes deep. What could be causing this?

I have tried adding `fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);` before the first `fread` call, but the first call still started at the same offset as before. I also tried using `rewind(infile)` to no avail. I did see that whether this problem occurred depended on the file being read. Some files would always start at position 0 while others would always start at some other offset.

Here is a minimal example of code that exhibits this problem on my machine. I am currently running Windows 10 and the code was compiled in Visual Studio.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE* infile;
    char* inname;
    char x;

    inname = argv[1];

    if ( (fopen_s(&infile, inname, "r")) != 0) {
        printf("Error opening file: %s\n", inname);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (infile == 0) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while (fread(&x, sizeof(char), 1, infile) == 1) {
        printf("%ld\n", ftell(infile));
        printf("%hhx\n\n", x);
    }


    fclose(infile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the file in binary read mode.

```
if ( (fopen_s(&infile, inname, "r")) != 0) {
```

to

```
if ( (fopen_s(&infile, inname, "rb")) != 0) {
```

---

From [fopen man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last
>   character or as a character between the characters in any of the
>   two-character strings described above. This is strictly for
>   compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all
>   POSIX conforming systems, including Linux. (**Other systems may treat**
>   **text files and binary files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a**
>   **good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program**
>   **may be ported to non-UNIX environments**.)

Comment: @kansas_bulldog382 Happy to help :)